# why is my fbx file is not fully textured when imported to unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, blender, fbx

[this is how the picture is imported] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQUO4.png)

[and this is how the picture is supposed to be] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDD16.png)

so the problem is that the assest in unity is not fully textured and part of it is transparent I dont know what causing it and would like to get solution if anyone knows how to fix that I found out that the problem is not in the texture but in the object it self for someone reason it doesn't show all the shape and only part of it how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That's because with FBX files you need to export separately textures

This will help you https://youtu.be/5UZ-niuRWz8?t=86

Comment: in my blender the texture is uploaded from my computer to a matiral so I don't see the option to separate them what can I do?

Comment: @neviot Try importing the project in unity and use it (you can use your blender project as a models)

Comment: before you export, try to go through the materials and "link" them, this will allow them to be embedded in the blend file and possibly will be exported with it